# jQuery DataTables with extra data

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to create a similar table like this https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html in which extra data is shown when plus icon is clicked.

This is what I am doing
http://jsfiddle.net/xcbj4Lac/

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            data: {"230660370":{"sale_order_item_code":"230660370","amount_recd":"570.05","net_margin_paid":35,"csp_mark_down":31,"net_mark_down":55,"received_return":"false","ignore":"false","settled_in_days":6,"return_in_days":null,"channel":"flipkart","file":"files\\ia2kth3crahupae7_2015-08-01_2015-08-31.csv","display_order_code":"OD003605696725113400","item_sku_code":"CA127261_42","order_date":"2015-08-10 15:44:00","sale_order_item_status":"DELIVERED","selling_price":"875.00","transactions":[{"settlement_ref_no":"NFT-150817314GN00056XXXXXXX","settlement_date":"2015-08-17 00:00:00","order_item_value_rs":"875.00","sale_transaction_amount_rs":"875.00","discount_transaction_amount":"0.00","refund_rs":"0.00","protection_fund_rs":"0.00","total_marketplace_fee_rs":"-267.50","service_tax_rs":"-37.45","amount_recd":"570.05","commission_rate":18,"total_offer_amount":"0.00","my_offer_share":"0.00","flipkart_offer_share":"0.00","file":"files\\ia2kth3crahupae7_2015-08-01_2015-08-31.csv"}]},"235780806":{"sale_order_item_code":"235780806","amount_recd":"661.25","net_margin_paid":24,"csp_mark_down":31,"net_mark_down":48,"received_return":"true","ignore":"false","settled_in_days":5,"return_in_days":16,"channel":"flipkart","file":"files\\ia2kth3crahupae7_2015-08-01_2015-08-31.csv","display_order_code":"OD003690008540721702","item_sku_code":"FR126136_38","order_date":"2015-08-20 09:56:00","sale_order_item_status":"CANCELLED","selling_price":"875.00","transactions":[{"settlement_ref_no":"NFT-150826078GN00136XXXXXXX","settlement_date":"2015-08-26 00:00:00","order_item_value_rs":"875.00","sale_transaction_amount_rs":"875.00","discount_transaction_amount":"0.00","refund_rs":"0.00","protection_fund_rs":"0.00","total_marketplace_fee_rs":"-187.50","service_tax_rs":"-26.25","amount_recd":"661.25","commission_rate":18,"total_offer_amount":"0.00","my_offer_share":"0.00","flipkart_offer_share":"0.00","file":"files\\ia2kth3crahupae7_2015-08-01_2015-08-31.csv"}]}},
            "columns": [
                {
                    "className": 'details-control',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                {"data": "sale_order_item_code"},
                {"data": "display_order_code"},
                {"data": "item_sku_code"},
                {"data": "selling_price"},
                {"data": "amount_recd"},
                {"data": "net_mark_down"},
                {"data": "net_margin_paid"},
                {"data": "csp_mark_down"},
                {"data": "received_return"},
                {"data": "sale_order_item_status"},
                {"data": "order_date"},
                {"data": "ignore"}
            ],
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]
        });
```

However I dont know why my table is showing no data available. Can you please help me debug it.

Comment: datatable  needs array as input, but you gave object as input . [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xnLqhxav/). not  with extra data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable accept object data too, we have to just add the following code.

```
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
```

Comment: i think it accepts array of objects. but you are saying it accepts object too, if possible can you provide a working fiddle that accepts object . i

Answer (score 0):

It's because your data isn't an Array. From the Datatables Doc:

"The main data source used for a DataTable must always be an array [...]"

https://www.datatables.net/manual/data